# if else -if unexpected Message

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, for-loop

I have a swing application that involves a `Container`, a `JButton`, a `JPanel`, a `JTextArea` and an array. The array of String objects and contains 5 elements.

I want to return all elements in the array by a method and compare each of them with the element entered by end user in the text area, after pressing a `JButton`.

If they are same a `JOptionPane` message displaying  the  matched element should appear. If  they are different  a JoptionPane  should show a message saying `Number Entered is not found in myArray` else, a message saying `please Enter something" should appear`

The problem I face is that when the end user enters a valid number a `JOptionPane` message saying: `Number Entered is not found in myArray` appear many times, e.g. when entering 4, a `JoptionPane` message saying
`Number Entered is not found in myArray` appear 3 times.

How do I prevent this message if the entered element is correct?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Array_Search extends JFrame {

    String myString[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

    public String[] get_Element() {
        String str[] = new String[myString.length];
        str = myString;
        return str;
    }

    public Array_Search() {
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final JTextField txt = new JTextField(
                "                                    ");
        JButton b = new JButton("Click Me ");
        panel.add(b);
        panel.add(txt);
        pane.add(panel);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                String[] str = get_Element();
                String s2 = txt.getText().trim();
                if (s2 != null && s2.length() > 0)
                    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                        if (s2.equals(str[i].trim())) {
                            JOptionPane option = new JOptionPane();
                            option.showInputDialog("" + str[i]);
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane option = new JOptionPane();
                            option.showInputDialog("Number Entered is not found in myArray");
                        }
                    }
                else {
                    JOptionPane o = new JOptionPane();
                    o.showInputDialog("please Enter something");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array_Search myArray = new Array_Search();
        myArray.setSize(500, 500);
        myArray.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify only that code in which you are facing error.

Comment: Your formatting was horrible. Don't put everything in quotation blocks, and you had some weird multi-spacing as well.

Comment: Note that you don't need `JOptionPane o = new JOptionPane(); o.showInputDialog("please Enter something");` You can simply do `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please Enter something");`

Comment: And note that you forgot `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shows message every time when non-matching element is found.

Instead, you need to look through all of the elements and display `Not found` message after that.
Something like this should work:

```
...
if (s2 != null && s2.length() > 0) {
    boolean isFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (s2.equals(str[i].trim())) {
            JOptionPane option = new JOptionPane();
            option.showInputDialog("" + str[i]);
            isFound = true;
            break;
        } 
    }
    if(!isFound) {
        JOptionPane option = new JOptionPane();
        option.showInputDialog("Number Entered is not found in myArray");
    }
} else 
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You return an empty Array in your get_Element method.
Can be fixed like that:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    String [] str = get_Element(); // replace this 
    String [] str = myString;      // with this
```

or change get_Element to:

```
public String[] get_Element() {
    return myString;
}
```

Note: by Java [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) use camel case for method names. getElement instead of get_Element.